# Drag and Drop grid on a panel

Tags: extjs

I have a panel and within the panel i have three grids.
I want to be able to move the grid by dragging and dropping.
I have the draggable: true and enableDragDrop: true, that seems to allow me to drag but not drop.

Any genius help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I do not have much experience, but setting those parameters will let you drag the grid, as you could experience. In order to "drop" it, I think you need to set a drop area, in order to tell where you want the grid to be dropped, in which area. I think this example about hospitals and patients can be useful, try to see: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/dd/dragdropzones.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to drop something that is draggable, you need to define an `Ext.dd.DropTarget` or `Ext.dd.DropZone` and define the behavior that you want when the item is dropped.  Use DropZone if there are multiple drop targets in a zone that handle the drop differently, but it sounds like you want DropTarget, which is used for dropping on a single element (such as inside your panel).

To make an entire panel be able to drop things onto, pass the panel into the constructor of DropTarget, and override the `notifyDrop` function:

```
var panelDropTarget = new Ext.dd.DropTarget(panel, {
    notifyDrop: function(dragsource, event, data) {
        // do something with the dragsource
    }
});
```

The `dragsource` that is passed into the function will have your grid in it (I think it will be `dragsource.panel`, but use Firebug debugging to determine exactly what that source object has in it).

Once you have a handle on the grid, you can reorder it in the panel, move itsomewhere, or define whatever behavior you want.